# Communicating with Jython/Java from Python (Subprocess)

Tags: java, python, scripting, subprocess, jython

My problem is somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371574/python-communicate-with-subprocess).

I try to communicate from Python with a Jython program (that needs to keep running because it communicates with a Java API).

However, i can't get the output in realtime, whatever i try:

```
p2=Popen([path_jython],stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False)
p2.stdin.write('test="hallo"\n')
p2.stdin.write('print test\n')
p2.stdin.flush()

for line in p2.stdout:
    print line
```

Nothing happens, the program blocks. It doesn't change when i iterate over `p2.stdout.readlines()` or `iter(md5.stdout.readline, '')` or when I repeatedly call `p2.stdout.read(1)` like suggested in the linked question.

If i add `print p2.communicate()` after the `flush()` however, i get the desired output:

`>>> ('hallo\r\n', '\r\n')`

but the program terminates afterwards...

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Or are there alternatives to communicate effectively with a running Jython process? Happy for any advice!

EDIT: Python 2.7.5, Jython 2.7.1b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. try to make `jython` stdout/stderr unbuffered, pass `-u` command-line argument
2. if you set `stderr=PIPE` then you should read it, otherwise a deadlock may occur if the child process fills the OS pipe buffer corresponding to its stderr. You could redirect it to stdout: `stderr=STDOUT`
3. set Python side buffering explicitely: `bufsize=1` (line-buffered)
4. use `iter(p.stdout.readline, '')` to avoid [read-ahead bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue3907) on Python 2

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['jython', '-u', ...], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
          bufsize=1)
print >>p.stdin, 'test="hallo"' #NOTE: it uses `os.linesep`
print >>p.stdin, 'print test'
p.stdin.close() # + implicit .flush()
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    print line, #NOTE: comma -- softspace hack to avoid duplicate newlines
p.stdout.close()
rc = p.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I built a class using Threading/Queue around it and asynchronous/non-blocking communication between python/jython works as expected now.