# Runtime.getRuntime().exec to pass parameter when prompted

Tags: java, database, postgresql, process, runtime.exec

I am using the below Java statement to start the PostgreSQL server from Java code. I am using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` method to achieve this.

```
 final Process startServer = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("PostgreQL -D data/dir/ start");
```

Here when the server is SSL enabled and if the key is password protected, in command line it prompts for password (see below lines). In this case how can I pass the password.

```
Is server running?
starting server anyway
waiting for server to start......Enter PEM pass phrase:....
```

Do we have any option to pass the password as a parameter, when prompted? or in PostgreSQL while starting do we have any provision to pass the keypassword (like `PostgreSQL -d data/dir/ -keyPass password start`)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112470/java-how-to-both-read-and-write-to-from-process-thru-pipe-stdin-stdout

Answer (score 4):

You can open the OutputStream of the process and pass the passphrase which will be read by the server as if you typed it is coming from STDIN.

```
final Process startServer = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("PostgreQL -D data/dir/ start");
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(startServer.getOutputStream());
ps.println(passPhrase);
```

Comment: Vikdor: Thanks for your time. So ps.println(passPhrase) will pass the password to command line is it ?

Comment: One more question, can this parameter (ps.println(passPhrase)) can be passed at beginning itself or should be passed only when it is prompted, if so then I should read the input stream and check when it is prompted and only by that time I should pass is it? Please clarify me.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to the answer provided above is to create a [password](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) file.

(e.g `~/.pgpass` file (%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf on Windows) formatted as:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

Comment: This password is not PostgreSQL server password, this is password for private key which is totally different from PostgreSQL server's password. Guess you have misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Start by having a look at [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), it will make you life much easier....

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("PostgreQL", "-D", "data/dir/" "start");
Process p = pb.start();

InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();

// Create a separate thread to read the input as needed...
// Create a seperate thread to deal with the output as needed...
```

Comment: Don't forget to either [`redirectErrorStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28%29) or `// Create a seperate thread to deal with the error as needed...`.  I am guessing that given `PostgreQL` (as opposed to `PostgreSQL`) we might be seeing some of the latter.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Why would you ever want to know when things go wrong?  Or report the fact? ;) +1 nice point