# How to get the output of a linux command at the same time it's printed on the terminal?

Tags: java, linux, wget

I'd like to get the wget output at the same time or some seconds after it's printed on the terminal. To explain what I'm trying to get look at this command `wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --no-parent http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/` it'll download this entire website, and during it's execution it'll output step by step the process it completed, this is what I'm trying to get. Do you guys know how can I do that?

This is what I have so far:

```
try {
    Process processWhoAmI = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --no-parent http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this from a terminal or does it have to be from within a program. If it's from a terminal, look at I/O redirection in the bash manual page.

Comment: @JimNutt It have to be from within a program. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), it will save you a lot of hassles when it comes to generating processes.

Basically, you need to get the processes's `InputStream` and read it.  This is connected to the processe's standard out.

You can use `ProcessBuilder` to redirect standard error through this stream as well, which will make life a lot easier...

And some examples...

- [Runtime.getRuntime().exec to pass parameter when prompted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639902/runtime-getruntime-exec-to-pass-parameter-when-prompted/14640059#14640059)
- [Running a java program from another java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218892/running-a-java-program-from-another-java-program/15220419#15220419)
- [How do I execute Windows commands in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452964/how-do-i-execute-dos-commands-in-java/16453653#16453653)
- [I'm not getting any output and probably the machine hangs with the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286042/im-not-getting-any-output-and-probably-the-machine-hangs-with-the-code/15286128#15286128)