# Error when calling Python from Java and passing parameters

Tags: java, jython

Below is the given code for calling Python from Java

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new test1( ).setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    try {
        PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), new String[0]);
        PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
        interp.set("firstName", args[0]);
        interp.set("lastName", args[1]);
        interp.execfile("‪C:\\Users\\priyank\\Desktop\\pythontest.py");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0" error..
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not pass any arguments, when you start your application. The args-array is empty (size = 0), but then you are trying to access the first element (index 0), which does not exist.

Comment: I have added two string to it, still i am getting the same error, please help me rewriting it, and if you can please tell me how to pass parameters to python from java.

Answer (score 0):

A pipe can be a better solution. Have a look at this thread:

[java: how to both read and write to & from process thru pipe (stdin/stdout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112470/java-how-to-both-read-and-write-to-from-process-thru-pipe-stdin-stdout) .

Comment: I did not understand this example, sorry I am new to Java and Python

Comment: What did you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Change the values to

```
interp.set("firstName", args[1]);
interp.set("lastName", args[2]);
```

it will work, as the first value is the python script file name but we are not adding that, please check that.