# Java Runtime Execution - Confirmation issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-interface, amazon-ec2, termination, starcluster

I am trying to develop a GUI application that creates and deletes elastic *Starcluster* clusters in *Amazon Elastic Compute 2*. So far I have managed to create and use these clusters from the graphic application, but I am running into a problem when I try to delete the clusters. The following is the method I have used to insert commands into the console (from my application):

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntimne();    
Process proc = rt.exec("command",null,dir);
```

The issue is that the system asks me for a *yes/no* confirmation which I cannot pass through making use of the method used in my application. So far I tried the following:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntimne();    
Process proc = rt.exec("y",null,dir); //y for yes
```

But the system keeps waiting for an answer, ignoring the command introduced in the application. The following is the log of the actual application requesting a confirmation:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:~$ starcluster terminate myCluster
StarCluster - (http://star.mit.edu/cluster) (v. 0.95.5)
Software Tools for Academics and Researchers (STAR)
Please submit bug reports to starcluster@mit.edu

Terminate EBS cluster myCluster(y/n)?
```

I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas about the matter. Feel free to ask more information if you consider it necessary to give an appropiate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your "y" to the process stdin stream.

Check the answer of Berry Tsakala given to that question: [java: how to both read and write to & from process thru pipe (stdin/stdout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112470/java-how-to-both-read-and-write-to-from-process-thru-pipe-stdin-stdout)