# Run Executable File, Listen To Output

Tags: java, command, output

I would like to make a bootstrap program for another program, which will accept commands that the bootstrap program sends it and also the bootstrap program needs to receive console output from the program it runs. How is this possible?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("COMMAND")
```

The code above executes a command, so I could do this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar file.jar")
```

But how to listen to the output and send commands to it as if they had been typed in a console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Process` object returned by `Runtime.exec()`, there are accessors for `getInputStream()`, `getOutputStream()` and `getErrorStream()` for `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` respectively.  You'll have to use threads and/or stream events to listen and read to or from the process you execute.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

See also: [java: how to both read and write to & from process thru pipe (stdin/stdout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112470/java-how-to-both-read-and-write-to-from-process-thru-pipe-stdin-stdout)

Although, if you're calling a java program, you might have better luck setting up `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` pairs and just calling the jar's `main()` routine directly rather than spinning up a new JVM.

Comment: in order to constantly listen to the output in your first method, is there anything better than having a while loop and read a line of the output stream each time?

Comment: Stream events which are part of the NIO framework.  Have a look at Netty for an example (http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/nio/NioEventLoop.html)